# Unit-testing classes that involve Entity creation via factory issues and considerations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

I have a Customer business entity which can be created only via CustomerFactory. However, I have questions as to how to perform unit testing for class that uses Customer object, because the unit test requires setup of Customer and its CustomerFactory whenever a customer is used.

The reason to using CustomerFactory rather than constructor is that it requires validation via ICustomerValidator. However putting the validation logic within constructor requires injecting the ICustomerValidator into constructor, which might not be desired.

For example, in performing unit test for implementation of ICustomerService, setup steps have to be created, including creation and setup of Customer and CustomerFactory (plus customer validation via ICustomerValidator, e.g IdValidFirstName). Furthermore, these setups have to be repeated for whenever Customer instance is used in unit test.

Below is the ICustomerService that is being unit-tested, but setup of Customer below has to created:

I want to unit-test this implementation

```
    public interface ICustomerService
    {
       bool AddCustomer(Customer customer);
    }

 public class Customer
    {
        internal Customer()
        { }

        public int Id { get; internal set; }

        public string Firstname { get; internal set; }

        public string Surname { get; internal set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; internal set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; internal set; }

        public bool HasCreditLimit { get; internal set; }

        public Company Company { get; internal set; }

        //... other properties
}
```

Please note that both implementation of ICustomerService and ICustomerFactory depends on ICustomerValidator

```
     public interface ICustomerFactory
        {
            Customer CreateCustomerWith(int id, string firstName, string surname, DateTime dateOfBirth, string emailAddress, Company company);        
        }

 public class CustomerFactory : ICustomerFactory
    {
        private ICustomerValidator customerValidator;
        public CustomerFactory(ICustomerValidator customerValidator)
        {
            this.customerValidator = customerValidator;
        }

        public Customer CreateCustomerWith(int id, string firstName, string surname, DateTime dateOfBirth,
            string emailAddress, Company company)
        {

        //validation logic here ...
        }
     }



 public interface ICustomerValidator
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> Errors { get; }

        bool IsValid(Customer customer);

        bool IsValidId(int id);

        bool IsValidFirstName(string firstName);

        bool IsValidSurname(string surname);

        bool IsValidDateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth);

        bool IsValidEmailAddress(string emailAddress);

        bool IsValidCompany(Company company);

    }
```

But I have to setup this in performing unit-test for ICustomerService, which seems lots of setup, or Is it correct, or is there a better way (I can make it re-use, but still I have to call it in the test for ICustomerService, Is it the ONLY way)?

```
private Customer CreatCustomer()
        {
            var customerId = 0;
            var firstName = "John";
            var surname = "Tom";
            var emailAddress = "John.Tom@unit.com";
            var dateOfBirth = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
            var company = new Company(34, "Unit", Classification.VIP);
            SetupForCustomerCreation(customerId,firstName,surname,emailAddress,dateOfBirth,company);

            var customer = this.customerFactory
                                        .CreateCustomerWith(
                                            customerId, firstName, surname, dateOfBirth, emailAddress, company);

            return customer;
        }

        private void SetupForCustomerCreation(int customerId, string firstName, string surname, string emailAddress, DateTime dateOfBirth, Company company)
        {
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidId(customerId)).Returns(true);
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidFirstName(firstName)).Returns(true);
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidSurname(surname)).Returns(true);
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth)).Returns(true);
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidEmailAddress(emailAddress)).Returns(true);
            this.customerValidatorMock.Setup(c => 
                                                c.IsValidCompany(company)).Returns(true);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell me why the downvote? This is a question that others might have.

Comment: Think you are missing some code. What is customerValidatorMock and why do you need to run Setup multiple times? P.S. I never downvoted you.

Comment: Please refer to my update that I added CustomerFactory. customerValidatorMock is used for both ICustomerService and ICustomerFactor.

Comment: So I don't see how with your current code base you can change much. You need to mock both the data for the customer and the validator code. Do you plan of having different validation mechanisms for a customer for real or is this just over engineering? I would just have a virtual method called Validate() or something like that which is easily mockable / testable and can be overloaded for a different class, unless there is a requirement that each customer OBJECT (runtime) has a different validation mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment to make Customer constructor public. After doing so you can use it freely without touching its factory all the time. By introducing not public constrcutor to a class makes it implicitly dependent on its factory, which is in most of the cases not recommended. It is better to have loosely coupled classes as it makes it easier to mantain and test

Comment: The reason to using CustomerFactory rather than constructor is that it requires validation via ICustomerValidator. However putting the validation logic within constructor requires injecting the ICustomerValidator into constructor, which might not be desired.

Comment: What if you can change your code to first to create a class and then pass it to your validator, if it is not valid throw an exception and discard it. In this way our API will became cleaner, you wouldn't need to reflect all your properties in validator, just pass the whole customer object.

Answer (score 0):

While I would strongly recommend @Alexandr-Mihalciuc answer the the right approach, you can expose your assembly where the customer class is defined as [InternalsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to your test assembly, and be able to create instances of the customer class in the test, even if you preserve your internal ctor.